MacOS doesn't show a window that is using with QTWebEngine
I am developing an application in python to help studying by using flashcards, this app should be on MacOS and Windows. The problem is that I compile my app with pyinstaller and in windows it works perfectly, however when I compile it for MacOS (I use Github Workflow since I don't have a mac), it gives me problems with the QWebengine processes, first it doesn't find them in the correct path and the app crashes, I solved this by adding this:
if platform.system() == "Darwin":
   os.environ['QTWEBENGINEPROCESS_PATH'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]),'Contents', 'Frameworks', 'PySide6', 'lib', 'QtWebEngineCore.framework', 'Helpers', 'QtWebEngineProcess.app', 'Contents', 'MacOS')
   os.environ['QTWEBENGINE_RESOURCES_PATH'] = (os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]),'Contents', 'Frameworks', 'PySide6', 'lib', 'QtWebEngineCore.framework', 'Resources')

With that the sudden closing of the app was solved, but now it doesn't generate the window that should be generated with this code:
import os
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDockWidget
from PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PySide6.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEngineSettings, QWebEnginePage
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl, Qt, QEventLoop
import relativeroute

class SpotifyPlayerWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # Window's configuration 
        self.setWindowTitle("Spotify Player")
        self.setGeometry(1040, 735, 499, 80)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        # Create the web viewer
        self.browser = QWebEngineView(self)
        html_path = os.path.join(relativeroute.resource_path("websarchives/spotify_player.html"))

        # Disable local security (so that html loads correctly)
        self.browser.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, True)
        self.browser.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.LocalStorageEnabled, True)
        self.browser.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.AllowRunningInsecureContent, True)
        self.browser.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PlaybackRequiresUserGesture, False)

        # Connect the `loadFinished` signal to a function that terminates the wait loop
        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.on_page_load)

        # Load HTML page
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl.fromLocalFile(html_path))

        # Set the browser as a central widget
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)


        # Wait until the page is fully loaded
        self.wait_until_loaded()

        self.start_music()

    def wait_until_loaded(self):
        """Wait until the page is fully loaded"""
        self.page_loaded = False
        loop = QEventLoop()  #Create temporary event loop

        # Exit the event loop when the page finishes loading
        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(loop.quit)
        loop.exec_()  # Run the event loop until 'loop.quit' is called

    def on_page_load(self):
        """Triggered when the page finishes loading"""
        self.page_loaded = True
        print("The page has loaded successfully The page has loaded successfully ")

    def play_music(self):
        
        if self.page_loaded:
            self.browser.page().runJavaScript("playMusic()")

    def pause_music(self):
        
        if self.page_loaded:
            self.browser.page().runJavaScript("pauseMusic()")

    def start_music(self):
        
        if self.page_loaded:
            self.browser.page().runJavaScript("startMusic()")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = SpotifyPlayerWindow()
    window.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec())

It is verified that the setting that you want to activate the music is saved and that the <spotify_player.html> file is in place.
It should open a window using the local <spotify-player.html> file, but it doesn't even generate the window where the website should appear.
This is the <spotify-player.html> if someone wonders:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Spotify Player</title>
    <style>
      
        body, html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;  /* Elimina el scroll */
            height: 100%;
        }

        iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: none;
        }

     
        body.dark-mode {
            background-color: #121212; /* Fondo oscuro */
            color: white; /* Texto blanco */
        }

      
        body.light-mode {
            background-color: white; /* Fondo blanco */
            color: black; /* Texto negro */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Cambia la altura y ancho del iframe a valores porcentuales -->
    <iframe id="spotifyPlayer" src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/album/7aAcs7w1vCsugitP9BvrM4?utm_source=generator" 
            frameborder="0" 
            allowfullscreen="" 
            allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; fullscreen; picture-in-picture">
    </iframe>
    
    <script>
        function updateTheme() {
            const isDarkMode = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;
            if (isDarkMode) {
                document.body.classList.add('dark-mode');
                document.body.classList.remove('light-mode');
            } else {
                document.body.classList.add('light-mode');
                document.body.classList.remove('dark-mode');
            }
        }

        updateTheme();

        window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener('change', updateTheme);

        // Asegurarse de que el iframe esté completamente cargado antes de enviar mensajes 
        const iframe = document.getElementById('spotifyPlayer'); 
        iframe.addEventListener('load', () => { 
            window.spotifyIframeLoaded = true;
        });

        function playMusic() {
            if (window.spotifyIframeLoaded) {
            iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({ command: 'resume' }, '*');
            }
        }

        function startMusic() {
            const iframe = document.getElementById('spotifyPlayer');
            iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({ command: 'play' }, '*');
        }

        
        function pauseMusic() {
            const iframe = document.getElementById('spotifyPlayer');
            iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({ command: 'pause' }, '*');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>



